# Change QGIS processing cache directory

Tags: qgis, cache

I'm working on an environment, where my C: directory is rather small. However by default, QGIS caches intermediate processing results there. Some processes are failing, due to size issues. I want to change the cache directory, but haven't found a clear setting to do so.

Under Network there is the option to configure a cache, but as I understand that does only apply for caching network data (e.g. WMS/WMTS data).

How can I change the processing cache under QGIS in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking around a bit, I found out that the cache directory for me is:
`C:\Users\hbh1\AppData\Local\Temp`

I found this "read-only" in the QGIS environment settings:

[image: Environment Variable Dialog in QGIS Settings]

This is set via environment variables and could be changed (system-wide) in your system environment variable dialog (Windows > System > Advanced System Settings). To change this only for QGIS, I used a custom variable - the dialog above the current environment variables.
Here I added two entries with `D:\Users\hbh1\QGIS_cache` ("TMP" and "TEMP", since both occurred) and restarted QGIS.

[image: Changed Cache via setting a custom environment variable]

Since I had choosen a folder in which I needed admin rights to write, the first attempt failed with QGIS being unable to load projects (unzip the .qgz to the cache). Starting QGIS as an admin / changing the folder then solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS 3.32 you can also set this on a per-algorithm level, if you are using algorithms via Python this might be easy to always integrate:

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog332/index.html#feature-allow-temporary-folder-to-be-temporarily-changed-through-the-algorithm-settings-panel

[image]